# aiohttp OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied

Tags: python, ssl, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Aiohttp version: latest
Python version: latest
Windows: 2019 datacenter x64

Im getting error after 5,10 requests
sending 5,6 requests get error sending requests get error loop, help me please.

My code

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
async def test():
  async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl=False)) as idk:
    while True:
      async with idk.get(f"mywebsite.com/endpoint") as gg:
        if gg.status == 404:
          exit()
        else:
          print(f" {gg.status} error.")


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(test())
```

Exception in callback

```
_ProactorBasePipeTransport._call_connection_lost(SSLError(1, '..._ssl.c:2685)'))
handle: <Handle _ProactorBasePipeTransport._call_connection_lost(SSLError(1, '..._ssl.c:2685)'))>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nomik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\events.py", line 84, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "C:\Users\nomik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 165, in _call_connection_lost
    self._sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nomik\Desktop\x.py", line 52, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(check_vanity())
  File "C:\Users\nomik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 671, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "C:\Users\nomik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 321, in run_forever
    super().run_forever()
  File "C:\Users\nomik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 638, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "C:\Users\nomik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1933, in _run_once
    event_list = self._selector.select(timeout)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nomik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 444, in select
    self._poll(timeout)
  File "C:\Users\nomik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 769, in _poll
    status = _overlapped.GetQueuedCompletionStatus(self._iocp, ms)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=WinError+10022. Concerning your (non-)answer below, you can [edit] your question instead if you wish to clarify something. As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I mean `ssl=False` and getting `SSLError` should be a pretty good hint. You code doesn't contain a valid URL, so I'm assuming that's not your actual code, and that you are using a URL which uses an HTTPS connection, which obviously won't work...